# Cors issues using sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, sharepoint, cors

i'm trying to query using REST API (sharepoint) and get some results.

this is where i've started

https://www.slideshare.net/CoreyRoth/fives-ways-to-query-share-point-2013-search-sharepoint-summit-toronto-2013, slide 31

this is what i have

```
document.getElementById("restApi")
            .addEventListener("click", restApi, false);
    function restApi() {

        var queryUrl = "https://myAppDomain.org/_api/search/query?querytext='" + $("#restSearch").val() + "'";

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: queryUrl,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var results = data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results;
            },
            error: function (error) {
            }
        });
    }
```

this is the problem.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load "https://myAppDomain.org/_api/search/query?querytext=x" No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63734' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

and another way i've tried providing password and username

```
headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                "password": "my password",
                "username": "my account name"
            },
```

for which i get

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://myAppDomain.org/_api/search/query?querytext=x. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63734' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

I'm using .net webApi, for which i've installed the cors packages, configuration

```
 // Enabled cors
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*") { SupportsCredentials = true });
```

The app are internal and i'm using windows credentials pass and account name.

So why am i getting this error, what do i do wrong?, i've searched and tried other solutions but always get the same problem related to

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested

Comment: Can you show your controller method that you are trying to hit?

Comment: not trying to hit any controller. i'm requesting from client directly ,,, this is why i'm not sure i event need cors packages, i guess o added in mostly because i wanted to be sure

Comment: So you dont have control over the Web API? You do not need CORS on the client side. Who ever you are making the request to needs to have to CORS enabled on their side.

Comment: yes but ,, i'm not a share point developer, is my first interaction with it and i already hate this technology (don't want to say bad things about it). share point is the culprit her, because the cors is enabled on the other side. I used something called CSOM first time, and there are security issues, now i'm trying with Rest API and there are cors issues

Comment: Haha, yeah not a huge fan either. But I think the key to getting this to work is enabling it on the sharepoint server (however that is done). Hopefully you can lookup some answers on how to get that done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open IIS
2. Go to Sites and find your Sharepoint site
3. Right-click -> Explore
4. Open web.config
5. Add the following code inside system.webServer node

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <configuration>
           <system.webServer>
               <httpProtocol>
                  <customHeaders>
                    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
                  </customHeaders>
               </httpProtocol>
           </system.webServer>
      </configuration>
   ```
6. Save and exit

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve my issue (partially, because i would have wanted to use CSOM rather then REST API on client side) by allowing cross domain calls from my application, directly to the application(sharepoint app) for which i made the request.

So in the requested app i've added the following file :

> web.config

in section :

> system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders

content :

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://myApplicationDomain.zzz" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If the server is being developed by you

Have you put the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost" in your .htaccess or in your webserver configuration?

You can, also, add that header in your response from the server.